# Define function outside quote block in elixir

Tags: elixir, metaprogramming, ex-doc

I've a simple macro that injects a function into the calling module.

```
defmodule MyModule do
  defmacro __using__(_opts) do
    quote do
      def run do
        IO.puts "Hello world"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This works as intended but because of the fact that the run function is nested inside the quote block, I'm unable to add documentation using ExDoc. I also want to define the run function outside as I feel that makes the code look better. Something like this:

```
defmodule MyModule do
  def run do
    IO.puts "Hello world"
  end

  defmacro __using__(_opts) do
    quote do
       # Some code to inject the run function
    end
  end
end
```

How do I go about doing this? In addition, how do I add documentation using ExDoc for a nested function?

Comment: Do you want to add the documentation to `MyModule.run` or do you want it to appear in the `run` function you inject into the module that does `use MyModule`?

Comment: @Dogbert I want to add the documentation to MyModule.run and in the module that does `use MyModule`

Comment: @Dogbert If I define the docs for the nested run function I get the documentation in the destination module but not the original module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `defdelegate` inside the `quote` and then define `run` in the main module.

```
defmodule MyModule do
  @doc """
  Prints "Hello world"
  """
  def run do
    IO.puts "Hello world"
  end

  defmacro __using__(_opts) do
    quote do
      defdelegate run, to: MyModule
    end
  end
end

defmodule A do
  use MyModule
end
```

`A.run/0` will get an auto generated doc by default which will point the user to `MyModule.run/0`. This can be customized by adding a `@doc ""` before `defdelegate`, if needed.

```
iex(1)> MyModule.run
Hello world
:ok
iex(2)> A.run
Hello world
:ok
iex(3)> h(MyModule.run)

                                   def run()

Prints "Hello world"

iex(4)> h(A.run)

                                   def run()

See MyModule.run/0.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works but what if the run function has arguments?

Comment: @MohideenImranKhan if you have say `def add(a, b) ...`, the `defdelegate` would be `defdelegate add(a, b), to: MyModule`.

Comment: @Dogbert Thank you.